# Reduce white space before and after multicols environment

Tags: spacing, equations, multicol

I wonder how to reduce the vertical space before and after a `multicols` environment. I have something like below

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
   {
      \begin{equation}\sum F_x = 0\end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\frac{dP}{dx} - p = 0\end{equation}
   }
   {
      \begin{equation}\sum F_y = 0\end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\frac{dQ}{dx} + q = 0\end{equation}
   }
   {
      \begin{equation}\sum M = 0\end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\frac{dQ}{dx} + q = 0\end{equation}
   }
\end{multicols}
```

But there is extra white space before and after the `multicols` environment. How can I reduce it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325930/reduce-white-space-before-and-after-multicols-environment?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoveflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: I used `\vspace{-0.5cm}`.

Answer (score 24):

While I wouldn't recommend it normally, you can also fiddle with the `\multicolsep` length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{6.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.5pt}% 50% of original values
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{3}
   \noindent
   \begin{equation}\sum F_x = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\frac{dP}{dx} - p = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\sum F_y = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\frac{dQ}{dx} + q = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\sum M = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\frac{dQ}{dx} + q = 0\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I would consider some of the other ways to do alignment, but if you want to use `multicol`, you need to add `\noindent`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{3}
   \noindent
   \begin{equation}\sum F_x = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\frac{dP}{dx} - p = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\sum F_y = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\frac{dQ}{dx} + q = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\sum M = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\frac{dQ}{dx} + q = 0\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```