# Right to Left multicolumns not working (compatibility issue with ExPeX?)

Tags: multicol, right-to-left, expex

According to the `multicol` [documentation](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf), on page 5 section 2.5, you can switch to right-to-left columns by invoking `\RLmulticolcolumns`. I have done this, yet it doesn't work. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Does `expex` not play nice with `multicol`?

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}    
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo Bar}

\RLmulticolcolumns

  \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{hebrew}

\ex\begingl%
    \gla אני מורה //  
    \glb ani more //  
    \glc I teacher //   
\endgl\xe%

\ex\begingl%
    \gla אני מורה //  
    \glb ani more //  
    \glc I teacher //   
\endgl\xe%

\ex\begingl%
    \gla אני מורה //  
    \glb ani more //  
    \glc I teacher //   
\endgl\xe%

    \end{hebrew}
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

(1) should be on right and (3) should be on left.
[image]

**EDIT:** I found a random, non-ExPeX [test case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37919/121944) where `RLmulticolcolumns` *does* work. Toggle it on and off to see it working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{6.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.5pt}% 50% of original values
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%\RLmulticolcolumns
\begin{multicols}{3}
   \noindent
   \begin{equation}\sum F_x = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\frac{dP}{dx} - p = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\sum F_y = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\frac{dQ}{dx} + q = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\sum M = 0\end{equation}
   \begin{equation}\frac{dQ}{dx} + q = 0\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think ExPex is the culprit here, since a simple `enumerate` environment shows the same issue.

Comment: @AlanMunn I added a working, non-ExPeX MWE in case it helps troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `polyglossia` package loads the `bidi` package whenever an RTL language is declared, and `bidi` modifies the behaviour of lots of packages to adapt them to RTL typesetting, so it's always useful to check the `bidi` documentation (`texdoc bidi-doc`) to see what it has done.

In this case, `bidi` has a different macro to change the direction of `multicol` columns: instead of the `multicol` macro `\RLmuticolcolumns`, `bidi` defines an `\RTLmulticolcolumns` macro. If you use this, things work.

As with all `bidi` issues, make sure that you load most package before declaring your RTL languages, since `bidi` modifies lots of package code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{expex}  
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo Bar}

\RTLmulticolcolumns % bidi version of \RLmulticolcolumns
\begin{hebrew}
\begin{multicols}{3}

\ex\begingl%
    \gla אני מורה //  
    \glb ani more //  
    \glc I teacher //   
\endgl
\xe%

\ex\begingl%
    \gla אני מורה //  
    \glb ani more //  
    \glc I teacher //   
\endgl
\xe%

\ex\begingl%
    \gla אני מורה //  
    \glb ani more //  
    \glc I teacher //   
\endgl
\xe%


\end{multicols}
\end{hebrew}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]